# Get height from reversing BMI calculation (oracle)

Tags: oracle

Seems that it should be simple enough to reverse engineer the bmi formula when you have the BMI and weight to get height -but perhaps not enough coffee today

(kg/power(m,2)) = BMI

but if I have

```
with T as (select 72.6 as kg, 28.35 as BMI_supplied  from dual)
```

what is the reverse to get the height (should be 1.6m)

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: sqrt(kg/bmi)   ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rearrange the equation:

| Step | Equation | Action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | BMI = weight / height<sup>2</sup> |  |
| 2. | BMI × height<sup>2</sup> = weight | *Multiply both sides by height<sup>2</sup>* |
| 3. | height<sup>2</sup> = weight / BMI | *Divide both sides by BMI* |
| 4. | height = SQRT(weight / BMI) | *Take the square root of both sides* |

So:

```sql
WITH T (weight_kg, BMI_supplied) AS (
  SELECT 72.6, 28.35 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT weight_kg,
       SQRT(weight_kg / BMI_supplied) AS height_m,
       BMI_supplied
FROM   T;
```

Which outputs:

> | WEIGHT_KG | HEIGHT_M | BMI_SUPPLIED |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 72.6 | 1.60026452839727746261804822638120931361 | 28.35 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=7f060066d02978e937e275e7e12980c0)*

Comment: Thanks. It was the SQRT function I was having challenges recalling (math wise!)